# How to restrict a time period in Firestore's rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to restrict a time period using Firestore.

For example a user can access an app only between 9:00 and 21:00.
I don't know how to store the restricted time. At first I though I should use timestamp type.
But I want for user to access based on hours. So I mean I need just hours.

Based on this article [Storing time only in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533597/storing-time-only-in-firestore),
Should I save the time like this?

```
 - startAccess : 900
 - endAccess: 2100
```

This data type is `Int` type.

And if I save those type in Firestore, I don't know how to filter it exactly.
I read an official document and we can restrict an access like this.

```
allow read: if
  request.time > something rule?
```

But if I use just `Int` type above, I think I can't filter the access time.
How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test this yet, But should look like:

```
allow read: if request.time.hours() >= 9 && request.time.hours() < 21;
```

Document [Interface: Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp)

Comment: I tried that. It did work only when I upload. Then I can't read properly.
But when the app restarts, it didn't work. I can read beyond the time of a setting.
Do you know why it happens?

Comment: And in Firestore rule `allow read: if request.time.hours() > 9 && request.time.hours() < 21` doesn't work. Is there a time difference?

Comment: I tested it, It works, But notice that `.hours()` return UTC time which is 8:00 right now.

Comment: So the `.hours()` return 8 right now, If you want to test it, try change first condition to 8.

Comment: I see. My region is UTC+9. So do you mean should I change +9 in Firestore rule?
And how did you test it and get `UTC time` ? I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: I tested this by using [Rules Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator#use_the), If you want number match your region simply just plus 9 on UTC time, So rules become `allow read: if request.time.hours() + 9 >= 9 && request.time.hours() + 9 < 21;`

Comment: It did work well. I also confirmed the debug way. Thank you.
I have a final question about those way. I thought those `request.time` is not working on Firebase Emulator, what about it? If those rule doesn't work on local dev(emulator), how do I make difference about Firestore rule on between prod in cloud and dev in emulator?

Comment: I think envirement setup is off this question, You should create another question for that.